# Удалить все теги <br></br> из текста

Tags: php

Здравствуйте всем.

Есть переменная в *PHP*-скрипте, содержащая текст, скажем, `$comment`. Переносы строк в тексте сделаны тегами `<br></br>`, причём тегов этих может быть как одна пара (открывающий - закрывающий), так и несколько (неограниченно пар).

Нужно заменить все эти `<br></br>` на `</p><p>` в переменной `$comment` перед её выводом.

Comment: Метки должны быть не `код`, `теги` и `программирование`, а языки программирования. `php` например

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, функцией [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
$comment = "<p>" . str_replace("<br /><br />", "</p><p>", $comment) . "</p>";
```

Можно добавить строчку, чтобы зачистить пустые абзацы:

```
$comment = str_replace("<p></p>", "", $comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого, наверное, Вам подойдёт:

```
<?php
    $comment = "TEXT <br>TEXT 1</br> TEXT <br> TEXT 2-1 <br> TEXT 2-2 </br> TEXT 2-3 </br> TEXT";
    $count = 0;
    do {
        $comment = preg_replace("/<br>(.+?)<\/br>/", "</p>$1<p>", $comment, -1, $count);
    }
    while ($count > 0);
    echo($comment);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$comment = str_replace('<br>', '<p>', $commnet);`

`$comment = str_replace('<br/>', '<p/>', $commnet);`

тогда произойдет замена всех тегов.